# Transact SQL - VARCHAR(8000) Data Type

Tags: t-sql

I've coded the Tran_GenerateColumnList stored procedure to dynamically create a comma delimited list of column values to be passed into an execution call where the columns exist in both the View and the Table. This database has a lot of columns on a particular table and I am exceeding the 8000 character limit for the VARCHAR data type. Any suggestions on a possible work around? Do I need to use LEN and create a second variable to concatenate to the first variable? Any input would be greatly appreciated.

http://pastebin.com/kRDevWTD

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you on SQL Server 2005 or higher? If so, can't you use `varchar(max)`? See also [SQL Server: When 8000 Characters Is Not Enough](http://blogs.lessthandot.com/index.php/DataMgmt/DBProgramming/MSSQLServer/sql-2000-when-8000-characters-is-not-eno) for ideas if you are indeed stuck on pre 2005

Comment: Hi SQLMenace, I am on SQL Server 2008. However, I would like to be compatible with SQL Server 2005 as well.

Comment: 2005 and 2008 both support varchar(max)